# Jedit editor ftp lastmodyfiaction file

Tags: ftp, jedit

jEdit editor "Local File Browser" has last modification column. It's cool!

[image: desired column]

How to set last modification file column in FTP plugin remote browser in jEdit editor?

[image: missing column]

Answer (score 0):

You need to post a feature request for the FTP plugin at https://sourceforge.net/p/jedit/plugin-feature-requests/. As far as I remember the plugin providing a file system can provide a flag whether it provides this information and the FTP plugin seems not to provide this bit of information, so the column is not shown.